# What is faster and more efficient in the following split cases?

Tags: python, performance, split

What is faster and more efficient, split multiple times and store their results in variables:

```
text = 'Allah is all in all. Allah sees you, and is with you, wherever you are, whatever you do.'

wahed_al_surat = text.split(',')[0]
thalatha_al_surat = text.split(',')[1]
tnan_al_surat = text.split(',')[2]
arbaa_al_surat = text.split(',')[3]
```

or store the splitted list one time and then access by index and store them in variables:

```
text = 'Allah is all in all. Allah sees you, and is with you, wherever you are, whatever you do.'

splitted = text.split(',') # List accessible by split
wahed_al_surat = splitted[0]
thalatha_al_surat = splitted[1]
tnan_al_surat = splitted[2]
arbaa_al_surat = splitted[3]
```

If not faster, what is more CPU and memory efficient between both ways?

Comment: I think second method is better because it calls split one time only.

Comment: @mohaned the second code sample uses `split` only once...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo yes it was mistake and edited.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `.split()` just *once* is faster, and you only need to create the list object just once to boot. Python won't optimise or inline extra method calls as it cannot know for certain that the same result will be produced each time.

You have a 3rd alternative here:

```
wahed_al_surat, thalatha_al_surat, tnan_al_surat, arbaa_al_surat = text.split(',')
```

This splits just once, and assigns each of the 4 resulting parts to the 4 names.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. I suspected that. The third one looks very interesting and more readable indeed.

Comment: Just to clarify. The proposed 3rd alternative works only if the length of the list produced by `str.split()` is known and constant. Value unpacking in Python requires that the number of left operands of assignment operator is equal to the length of iterable to unpack (right operand).

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: You can give `str.split()` a 2nd argument to limit the number of times the split takes place; you can use this to set an upper bound to the number of values produced; `str.split(',', 3)` would result in at most 4 values. In Python 3 you can also give one of the left-hand names a `*` prefix to catch any extra values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right. However: 1. You don't want to limit the number of splits sometimes. 2. The question doesn't specify Python version. _I don't feel in charge to incorporate all the information from our comments into your answer but I kindly suggest you to do so, to make it complete. But who am I to tell the Python master what to do :)_

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: it depends on what you want to do; if it is an error to get more or fewer elements, then you don't need to split that many times. I focused on the speed aspect here, and we don't need to clutter things up with a full exposé on handling splits with more or fewer elements I don't think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters apparently you're right with keeping the answer on topic. OK then.

Answer (score 1):

For such questions you can always check the time taken by using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module as follows

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> 
>>> code_to_test_1 = """
... text = 'Allah is all in all. Allah sees you, and is with you, wherever you are, whatever you do.'
... 
... wahed_al_surat = text.split(',')[0]
... thalatha_al_surat = text.split(',')[1]
... tnan_al_surat = text.split(',')[2]
... arbaa_al_surat = text.split(',')[3]
... """
>>> 
>>> 
>>> code_to_test_2 = """
... text = 'Allah is all in all. Allah sees you, and is with you, wherever you are, whatever you do.'
... 
... splitted = text.split(',') # List accessible by split
... wahed_al_surat = splitted[0]
... thalatha_al_surat = splitted[1]
... tnan_al_surat = splitted[2]
... arbaa_al_surat = splitted[3]
... """
>>> 
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit(code_to_test_1, number=10000000)
14.445806980133057
>>> 
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit(code_to_test_2, number=10000000)
4.4506120681762695
>>>
```

Comment: Nice tip. The difference between the two isn't not negligible as can be seen.